# dockerClient.createContainerCMD doesn't link Selenium node to Hub

Tags: java, selenium, docker

I'm trying to start Selenium node Docker container with `java-docker lib`, ending up with node not linked to the hub

```java
container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(image)
        .withExposedPorts(exposedPort)
        .withHostConfig(new HostConfig().withPortBindings(bindings))
        .withName(name)
        .withEnv("HUB_HOST=selenium-hub")
        .withEnv("HUB_PORT=4444")
        .exec();

dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
```

I'm trying to mimic my docker-compose which is like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    selenium-hub:
            restart: always
            image: selenium/hub:latest
            ports:
              - 4444:4444

    chrome:
            restart: always
            image : selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest
            ports:
              - 6001:5900
            depends_on:
              - selenium-hub
            environment:
              - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
              - HUB_PORT=4444
            links:
              - selenium-hub:hub
```

So, I figured that the below should cover `HUB_HOST` and `HUB_PORT` in docker-compose

```
.withEnv("HUB_HOST=selenium-hub")
.withEnv("HUB_PORT=4444")
```

However, I don't know what should be the java equivalent of the depends_on section.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, if you are using docker-compose that do not use linking. `selenium-hub:hub` so you should better to use the alias that is `hub`.

```
("HUB_HOST=hub")
```

You can also remove ENV, you can use the `hub` host directly.

In docker-compose on the container can reference to another container with the name of container, no lining is required.

and I also assume that you are running selenium-hub from the same docker-compose.

```
chrome:
        restart: always
        image : selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest
        ports:
          - 6001:5900
        depends_on:
          - selenium-hub
        environment:
          - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
          - HUB_PORT=4444
```